# SUM IIF Expression returning an error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a simple expression that should work,but it keeps returning an error. 
Please keep in mind, the Parameter is a Multi elect Parameter.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Month.Value = Month(Today())  AND Fields!Year.Value = Year(Today()) AND Fields!Warehouse.Value = Parameters!warehouse.Value, Fields!Budget.Value, 0), "Budgets")
```

Comment: What is the error and what is your expected behavior if there are multiple warehouses selected?

Comment: It just says #ERROR
and what the expression should do is Get the sum of budgets for the particular warehouses. And in particular for the current month.

Comment: I tested this and it works fine. One thing that is easy to miss with this is the parameter is case sensitive. Make sure you have the correct casing.

Comment: I often run into this similar issue, make sure the data types match too.  For instance, if Budget.Value is a decimal, you may need to change your 0 to 0.00

Comment: Its weird, NOTHING worked but 0 was an issue. I didn't try 0.00. Maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parameter is multi-value, the values are passed as an array. One way to handle this is by combining the values into a comma-separated string.

So you would replace `Fields!Warehouse.Value = Parameters!warehouse.Value` with:

```
InStr(Join(Parameters!warehouse.Value, ","), Fields!Warehouse.Value) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. Even without the Warehouse Parameter it gives me an error. Is there something wrong with my expression. I feel totally stumped on this.

Comment: If you preview this report in Visual Studio it will tell you what the error actually is. There are many issues that could cause errors even if the syntax of the expression is correct. For example, where is the expression, is it within in any groups? And is "Budgets" really the name of a dataset or group in your report?

Comment: Thanks figured it out. It doesn't seem to like the 0 and instead requires NOTHING.